# Laravel 4 PHP Framework: View is not auto rendered?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am probably miss something, but can't figure out problem myself.

I am getting white screen (no logs in storage/logs and 200 code in Apache logs). I think that return View::make() is not passing view string.

In routes.php

```
Route::get('/home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'))->before('guest');
```

In filters.php

```
Route::filter('guest', function(){
if (Auth::check() === true) {
    return Redirect::route('dashboard')->with('flash_notice', 'You are already logged in!');
}});
```

In HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
public function index()
{
    return View::make('login');
}}
```

In views/login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.login')
```

In views/layouts/login.blade.php just HTML

Once I change return View::make('login'); to echo View::make('login'); I get rendered view.

I did install same codebase previously and it worked (yes, it was Laravel 4 as well), so I wonder this somehow related to new library versions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have a $layout property configured in your BaseController?

Comment: @petkostas I don't. Should I manually configure it? In BaseControll I have only `protected function setupLayout()
 {
  if (is_null($this->layout))
  {
   $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
  }
 } ` And layout is null.

Comment: Can you paste your login.blade.php file?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/1YyTjQRw) When I put die() before closing html tag I see rendered view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a master file base.blade.php inside your views/layouts folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>Signin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  body {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .form-signin {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 330px;
      padding: 15px;
  }
  .form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
@section('maincontent')
@show
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then in your login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('maincontent')
<form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST" >
    @if ($errors->first('login'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" >
            {{$errors->first('login')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if ($errors->first('password'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" >
            {{$errors->first('password')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if(Session::has('flash_notice'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" >
            {{Session::get('flash_notice')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if(Session::has('flash_success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" >
            {{Session::get('flash_success')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" name="login" autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" >
    <label class="checkbox"></label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
  @stop
```

Comment: I tried both cases: with *.php and *.html and still no luck. If that helpful I got 2 files generated in app/storage/views/ [link](http://pastebin.com/7eQrTnmF)

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake it should be blade.php the extension

Comment: Don't worry =) Wonder why Laravel does not render those views. Since I change return to echo and they are rendered, probably problem is not in the view itself? Maybe some Parent Class which responsible for rendering is not doing it's job? Can I use echo in every controller instead?

Comment: After more deep debugging I figured out that problem is related to upgrade from Laravel 4.0 to version 4.1
To be more specific: "Undefined index: expire_on_close". I just added 'expire_on_close' => false, to app/config/session.php
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to see you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change Route:

```
Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', 'before' => 'guest', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

Comment: Same result. Looks like problem is in the View/Controller.

Comment: Try installing debugbar and make a check of what is returned and if the request if ok.

Comment: I even got "compiled" view in app/storage/views: `<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.login', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>` I wonder why switch return View::make('login'); to echo View::make('login'); in controller does the trick.

Comment: Was the code in the link you provided your actual template? If yes then your template is wrong and that is why it's not working, you need to create a layout and extend the login from there:

Comment: Code in the link is sitting at app/views/layouts/login.blade.php Template is app/views/login.blade.php and has only one line with no spaces: @extends('layouts.login')